# Django connect mysql issue

Tags: mysql, django

I am connecting my mysql database to django.While migrating or running django app it shows following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

My database is accessible configuration is also correct in my config file.As when i type wrong database name it shows no database found.

```
[client]
database = vs4
user = newuserq
password = tooq
default-character-set = utf8
```

How to fix this error and why in this error it is asking for 'root' user, i have written 'newuser' user in my django config.

Comment: From the information you mentioned, I think your database conenctor does not load configuration from your db config file

Answer (score 1):

In your `setting` should look like this. And please check you have user-created `newuserq` with proper access.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'vs4',
    'USER': 'newuserq',
    'PASSWORD': 'tooq',
    'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
    'PORT': ''
  }
}
```

Comment: When i changed user to root it worked.Not working from different user other than root.

Comment: Then you should check permissions for that user.